# CSS background-image overlapping

Tags: css

Fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/ildaroit/evL7tn6r/

```
.video-wrapper {
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.video1 {
    border: 0px dotted black;
    height: 420px;
    /*height:50vw;*/
    background: url("http://learn.shayhowe.com/assets/images/triangles/triangles.svg") left -3px no-repeat, url("http://learn.shayhowe.com/assets/images/triangles/triangles.svg") right -3px no-repeat;
    /* background-position: left, right;*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

How to make the image not overlapping center div content on decreasing windows size? 
Like here: [learn.shayhowe.com](http://learn.shayhowe.com)

Now, left and right image overlap `.video` but need to make it fixed or something else.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Add `z-index: 100; background: #fff;` To your `.video-container`?

Comment: tnx guy, but i think this is not the best decision - images must be openet on resize from the side background. like here learn.shayhowe.com

Comment: and when i resize image bg-img elements will be cuted by central div, and this why i need bg-img always static to central div

Comment: something like that? https://jsfiddle.net/evL7tn6r/4/

Comment: No Joseph, that is not right :(

Answer (score 0):

hello do you mean like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/evL7tn6r/6/

just add a wrapper to your video1

```
.page{
    width:100%; /*this is not really necessary*/
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and a min-width to the video

you can adjust the min-width to set the minimum space between the graphics